# Inputting backtick (`) in LaTeX (italian keyboard, Windows XP)

Tags: windows, characters

I started writing my thesis in LaTeX, and I noticed there's the need of the backtick (`) char in many cases. I'm working on a Windows XP-mounting laptop whose keyboard is italian, and numpad-less. This makes wery hard inputting the backtick since italian keyboards don't come with a backtick key and Windows' key combination for the backtick requires a numpad.

I'd rather not map my keyboard with a different layout, since I don't usually need the backtick apart from when writing with LaTeX. Is there an escape sequence, or a way of directly inputting the ASCII code for the backtick? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need backtick for typesetting accented letters?  Why don't you encode your source with UTF8, load `inputenc` package with `utf8` option and insert the letters from keyboard?

Comment: You can use `\lq` for the backtick. The Italian module for `babel` defines `""` as equivalent to `\`\`` (double backtick)

Comment: for Windows ALT + 96

Comment: @giordano No, actually no, I needed it just for double quotation marks, but @egreg was correct, "" is rendered as ``if you use the babel package for italian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
`a
```

or equivalently

```
`\a
```

is just syntax for the character number of `a` so if you know those things you could just use `97` (with a trailing space) instead.

Alternatively the backtick is ASCII 96 and 64 off that is 32 which is space so you can use the control-space notation and

```
^^ a
```

or

```
^^ \a
```

work as long as `^` has its usual superscript catcode meaning.

You should never need this in a document though, just in code sections.  If you mean you need

```
\`{e}
```

To get an accent then you should be able to just use `è` directly if you specify the correct input encoding.

Finally if you use of the backtick is to get quotation marks

`this' or ``this''

Then you can use `\lq` (and `\rq` for symmetry to get `'`).

Comment: You forgot ``\`{}`` which just outputs a backtick, too

Comment: @TheConstructor no I didn't forget,  that outputs a grave accent which is a different thing altogether, and if you can not type `\`` on your keyboard, then you can not type `\\` ` either.

Comment: I do get a backtick in the output (at least with xetex; which is what I want), but you are right: it is not related to this question. It seems I was too fascinated by your answer to fully read the question.

Comment: @TheConstructor you get a grave accent over an empty base, that isn't the same character as a backtick